# How to send a newsletter with mailjet's Rest Java API?

Tags: java, rest, mailjet

I see in v3 reference in mailJet's site http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/newsletter-send/ there is the following example:

```
curl -s -X POST \
--user "$MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC:$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE" \
https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/newsletter/:id/send
```

but I can't find in all your code any example how it should be done with mailjet Java API
https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the response of mailJet's support their Java Wrapper is not completed and majority of REST API they still don't cover. So if you are going to use mailjet-apiv3-java library you should be ready to implement by yourself some REST commands.

Comment: Hi @igalisra

Sorry we didn't get back to you sooner on that issue. A clarification though: the java wrapper supports all resources of the REST API. What it doesn't (_yet_) cover are the actions, which is why you can't send newsletters at the moment.

We are aware that this is a problem and this is on our roadmap. As a matter of fact, we recently implemented the [Send API](http://dev.preprod.mailjet.com/guides/send-api-guide/) in the wrapper.

I can't promise you any kind of eta on the implementation of the actions though. If this is a problem, feel free to open a PR ;-)

Comment: Hi, our new Java wrapper released few months ago now fully supports those actions. You can learn more about it on our blog https://www.mailjet.com/blog/api/mailjets-new-java-and-php-clients-make-integration-easy-for-all